# Calico getting Hung when installing with k8

Tags: calico

Being a newbie I was trying to install calico with `minikube`.
I did downloaded it from https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v0.20.0 into my Ubuntu OS.

I tried the following commands to install it:

```
minikube start --network-plugin=cni
```

Then downloaded https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/blob/master/v2.6/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/calicoctl.yaml into my `/usr/local/bin/` location of Ubuntu

Finally tried d to install by
 `kubectl apply -f calico.yaml`

But after that command the terminal hunged up for a long time without any response.

I tried couple of time but it resulted the same.
Please help, I am not able to install it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I will suggest to get the latest `minikube` version from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v0.23.0).
Once you are done getting your latest `minikube`, there are 2 ways to install and run **Calico** with `minikube`:

1. policy-only mode
2. networking (includes policy) mode

With policy-only mode without networking:

```
minikube start --network-plugin=cni --host-only-cidr 172.17.17.1/24 \
    --extra-config=kubelet.PodCIDR=192.168.0.0/16 \
    --extra-config=proxy.ClusterCIDR=192.168.0.0/16 \
    --extra-config=controller-manager.ClusterCIDR=192.168.0.0/16 \
    --extra-config=controller-manager.CIDRAllocatorType=RangeAllocator \
    --extra-config=controller-manager.AllocateNodeCIDRs=true
```

Then use `kubectl apply -f https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/blob/master/v2.6/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubernetes-datastore/policy-only/1.7/calico.yaml`

or with networking (which also includes policy) mode which configures the networking and provides policy:

```
minikube start --network-plugin=cni --host-only-cidr 172.17.17.1/24 \
    --extra-config=kubelet.PodCIDR=192.168.0.0/16 \
    --extra-config=proxy.ClusterCIDR=192.168.0.0/16 \
    --extra-config=controller-manager.ClusterCIDR=192.168.0.0/16
```

then `kubectl apply -f https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/blob/master/v2.6/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubernetes-datastore/calico-networking/1.7/calico.yaml`

For more ref:-   https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/1013#issuecomment-325689943

Hope that help you to start

Comment: I taken the latest minikube and tried policy-only mode .. it worked smooth ! Thanks :)